# Facebook PHP SDK get User Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am a little confused and not sure what to do with the Facebook API.

So I set up a webhook for getting Graph API updates, when the user changes its name/email etc. It works perfectly, I am getting the json and I can see what fields have been changed.

But where to go now. I tried to get the accessToken with the userID and appID but I could not get it going. I was able to get the AppAccessToken but I cannot query the user data with that (only id and name) so i need the UserAccessToken.

How do I receive the actual changed data from the

```
$fb->get("/{userID}?fields=name,email")
```

Thank you for your help, there is so many things on web, I cannot really figure out what I need.

All best,
Luke

Comment: Which version of SDK do you use?

Comment: V4_5.0.0 :) should be the latest release

Answer (score -1):

```
$accessTokenEntity = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken();
$accessToken = $accessTokenEntity->getValue();

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name',  $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Didn't have chance to actually test it, but according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/AccessToken/5.0.0) it should work.

Comment: For my understanding it is a object that will be returned by the login process. So i am missing the actual login or something that gives me the users accesstoken by his id. The user does not actually trigger the access because the webhook does so i cannot use redirecturlhelper and either canvashelper because the script is calls by the webhook and not throug a canvas. I thought of using offline_access and store the lifelong accesstoken in my database but id rather would like to get access through a call if that is possible...

Comment: So this does not work. The problem here is that the server triggers the login and only has the id of the user but no sessions and others. So how should the server now who "me" is and what accesstoken to fetch. I looked it up and offline_acces is not available anymore so there must be a way where I can get access to thw data of a user with just the id and my appid aswell as the appsecurity. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: User tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days. If your stored token is older than that and therefor has become invalid, you _have_ to send the user through the login flow again to create a new token; there is no other way.

Comment: @CBroe i am a bit confused with docs on fb , can you tell me how can we extend to 60 days ??